# Building ruby 1.9.3-p194 via RVM fails

Tags: raspbian

Edit: Workaround is simply to use ruby 1.9.3-p125 instead.

I've installed ruby version manager (I'm using Raspbian as downloaded this morning), and I ran `rvm install ruby` to download and compile the latest stable ruby (1.9.3-p194).

It spends a while compiling then fails with a message saying something about `make` failed (message has gone off screen so don't know exact text), and directing me to a log file at `/home/pi/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log`:

```
[2012-07-25 02:14:58] make 
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -shared
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -fPIC 
        XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
        CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/armv6l-linux-eabi -I./include -I.
        DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9  
        SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  
linking miniruby
math.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
```

I've read through the output of both `rvm notes` and `rvm requirements` and I seem to have satisfied all of the listed dependencies.

How can I make it compile properly?
TIA.

Comment: It looks like a bug with the build to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Debian packed Ruby to start with.  Basically, if you don't have specific well defined needs, do use pre-packaged software. You will get updates when security bugs come. You will get controlled updates when a new version of the software arrives.

When it comes to libraries for Ruby, like Rails, I would suggest that you use the Debian package, because of the previous reason.  But there there are some useful tools to download and run the bleeding edge if you really need that.

I would recommend you to check out Debian's wiki page about Ruby and how to use the packaged version. http://wiki.debian.org/Ruby

Have a good hacking time with Ruby.

Comment: At least on Ubuntu, I've had a pile of problems in the past using the packaged rubies. Also, I like to use RVM's gemset feature.